# Is this a problem with my distro or the application?

Tags: linux, archlinux

I hope someone can help me with this :)

I am running Arch Linux and am trying to get a game to work (Penumbra Overture). I have downloaded the executable, checked the md5 and they match, installed it in a directory. However when I try to execute the file an error appears saying:

```
bash: ./penumbra.bin: No such file or directory
```

It does exist, I am in the right folder and it is set as executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kumagoro users 6814000 Apr 15  2010 penumbra.bin
```

file penumbra.bin says:

```
penumbra.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped
```

ldd penumbra.bin says:

```
        not a dynamic executable
```

So, is this a problem with my distro or the application?

Thanks

Comment: Is your Linux at 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Damn, I just realised it is 64 bit. I should have looked there first. I'm going to have to create a 32 bit environment for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the interpreter for the binary. Check with

```
readelf -a penumbra.bin | grep -i program.interp
```

what it wants.

Comment: [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]

Comment: (And that file is then missing.)